# add_query_vars does not work

Tags: wp-query, query

I have added this code in the TwentyFourteen theme's functions.php file.

```
function add_query_vars($aVars) {
    $aVars[] = "msds_pif_cat";
    return $aVars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
```

Then on the index.php file, I have added this:

```
$sMsdsCat = urldecode($wp_query->query_vars['msds_pif_cat']);
var_dump($sMsdsCat);
```

It does not return anything.

I have tried to print the `$wp_query` and it does not include that variable either. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try `get_query_var( 'msds_pif_cat' )`? (it's a wrapper). What does your request look like?

Comment: it does not return anything either. I only added the above code in hte functions.php file and then the other code on the index.php file, so that is just a plain index url of WordPress installation. Could you explain what you mean by the request?

Comment: So your request is like `http://example.com/?msds_pif_cat=123` ?

Comment: ok great, what was the problem?

Comment: My mistake, I thought that the above function will automatically add the variable in the query and that would be accessible even on the plain URL without passing these parameters, but your comment gave me the idea that it would be only available if it is included in the request url. I could not accept your answer as it is a comment.

Comment: You might consider answering your own question and vote/accept it so you could close the question.